# Detect if iOS device is connected to internet via Ethernet, not Wi-Fi?

Tags: ios, networking, wifi, ethernet, reachability

Just wondering if it's possible to tell if the active LAN connection is Ethernet (via USB adapter for iPad, etc.) ... Not the built-in Wi-Fi.

Comment: how you connect iPhone device with ethernet.

Comment: hows your device connected via Ethernet ? It should be wifi i think!

Comment: It's a seldom used but known trick. https://lifehacker.com/hack-together-a-way-to-connect-an-ipad-or-iphone-over-e-1770270331